# Determining and printing file size in Java

Tags: java, file-io, filesize, printwriter

The method below returns file size as 2. Since it is long, I'm assuming the file size java calculates is 2*64 bits. But actually I saved a 32 bit int + a 16 bit char = 48 bits. Why does Java do this conversion? Also, does Java implicitly store everything as long in the file no matter if char or int ? How do I get the accurate size of 48 bits ?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            File f = new File("C:/sam.txt");
            int a= 42;
            char c= '.';
            try {
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  
                }
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
                pw.write(a);
                pw.write(c);
                pw.close();
                System.out.println("file size:"+f.length());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }

        }
```

Comment: It helps to learn how to use a hex editor to check what is really in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You wrote two characters. Writers are used for textual data, not for binary data. The [documentation of write(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write%28int%29) says:

> Writes a single character.

Since the default character encoding of your platform stores those two characters as a single byte (each), the file length is 2 (2 bytes: the length of a file is measured in bytes, [as the documentation says](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29)). Open the file with a text editor, and see what's in there.

The Java API doc is really useful to know what a class or method does. You should read it.

Comment: exactly that's what happens... Java takes the int as a unicode code which can have any length between 1 and 4 bytes. print() instead of write() can be used if this is not desired.

Comment: @yankee: Nope: the int is simply cast to a char.

Comment: okay. i changed pw.write to pw.print(a) and pw.print(c) and now the method returns file length = 3 ... my question is an int is 32 bits = 4 bytes so how were those 4 bytes stored in the file and then when i wrote a single char how was it saved. Why is the result = 3 bytes when java uses char as 16 bit OR 2 bytes ... ?

Comment: @JB: Yes, it is casted to a char, which means that it can't have 4 bytes but just 2 bytes, but that does not change anything about the variable behaviour of the function. Can be 1 byte or 2 byte, depending on character it represents.

Comment: @Pan: Because you're writing the int as text. Writers are used to write text, not bytes. Read my answer once again. The int 42 is written as the char '4' followed by the char '2'. Open the file with a text editor to understand, and read the API doc. You must use Streams to write binary data. Read the Java tutorial about IO : http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: @Pan: 2 Bytes just get ignored: Writes a single character.  The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

Comment: Oh... Sry... The last answer was still directed at the write() method. print() is different of course...

Comment: But even if it stored it as 3 chars shouldn't java store it as 3*2 = 6 bytes as a char is 2 bytes in Java ? So why are chars still 3 bytes ?

Comment: Because when textual data is written to a file, the encoding used in memory (which uses 2 bytes per char, whatever the char is) isn't used. Rather, the encoding of the platform is used. On some platforms, it's ASCII, which uses a single byte for all chars. If the printed char is not a valid ASCII char, it will be replaced by a question mark. On some others, it might be UTF-8, where some chars (latin chars, digits, ...) are stored as a single byte, and some others (greek chars, for example) are represented as a sequence of two or more bytes.

Comment: The Java type `char` is not the same thing as the concept of a character. `char` is a 2-byte type, but it holds a code point which may be **encoded** when the file is written (which is part of the Writer's responsibility). UTF-8 encoding will encode code points 0 through 127 with one byte.

Comment: so is encoding dependent on the operating system or it can change within versions of operating system ? will all windows os versions have cp1252 encoding always ?

Comment: I guess the Japanese version of Windows doesn't use cp1252, for example. If you want to use a specific encoding to write your text use a PrintWriter wrapping an OutputStreamWriter constructed with a specific encoding/charset. See the api doc of OutputStreamWriter for additional information. Note that when reading a text file, you may also specify an encoding, or use the default one.

Answer (score 1):

both calls to write are writing a char, which is 16 bits in memory, but since

```
new PrintWriter(f)
```

uses the default character set encoding (probably ASCII or UTF-8 on your system), it results in 2 bytes being written.